# Why do one liner functions require braces?

Tags: c, language-design

We can do this

```
if(condition)
    doThis();
```

and this

```
while(condition)
    doThat();
```

but not this

```
int giveMeFive()
    return 5; // Error: expected a '{'
```

Why not?

I'm aware that the language grammar requires `{` and `}` on function definitions. I'm asking about the rationale for the difference between conditional statements (which don't require braces) and function definitions (which do).

Comment: Because the language's grammar says so.

Comment: I already knew that. I just wondered if there is a logical reason.

Comment: the last one is a method definition and not a conditional/iterative instruction

Comment: And BTW you shouldn't use the other mentioned forms either, they just make your code less readable, maintainable and error prone!

Comment: Frankly I'd prefer to disallow the first two forms than to allow the third.

Comment: It's more a C thing because it affects all the languages that inherit its syntax like Java, C#, C++ and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nonsensical.

Comment: OT: In C++ you can avoid them [under some circumstances](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df6aed03d14e6729)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the question only seems nonsensical until an insightful answer is given. Then it becomes a question we can all learn from.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It might be off-topic for some other reason (subjective, possibly). But it *clearly isn't* nonsensical, since quite a lot of users (including some high-rep people) apparently understood it very well and gave perfectly coherent answers.

Comment: I now see that this question probably belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com but I can't move it.

Comment: Which part of the question doesn't make sense to you, @ThePara? You understand the concept of conditional expressions followed by statements rather than blocks, right? This question asks why function prototypes can't *also* be followed by statements rather than blocks. Do you not see the apparent pattern in the three blocks of code? The asker has identified something that seems inconsistent in the language and wants to understand it better.

Comment: @RobKennedy before claiming that I don't understand something about the problem, you might as well reconsider reading the question. What you stated is all nice and pink and fluffy, but OP outright asked "why we can't do thing X", to which the answer is Borgleader's first comment: "because the grammar says so". If OP really wanted to "understand [this] better", he should have elaborated as to why he thinks this is an issue. But dumping "why X" to SO is not a meaningful question at all.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Rob concluded that some part of the question doesn't make sense to you because you said the question is nonsensical

Comment: @cambunctious I didn't write "meaningless" or "incomprehensible", I wrote "nonsensical". Perhaps I should have written "rhetorical", "pointless" or "overly general" instead?

Comment: I just spent 30 minutes writing an historical answer and then its marked as off topic before I can post.  This is a good design question. Don't be so hasty! @/πάντα-ῥεῖ

Comment: @cambunctious at Programmers, it would likely be quickly closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/16528/31260), and possibly heavily downvoted for [thorough lack of research effort](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)

Comment: @black C# just recently added a different syntax to do this: `int giveMeFive() => 5;`.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking about, based on your comments.

Comment: @gnat: It's not a duplicate of [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/16528/31260), which doesn't mention function definitions. Nor does it show a lack of research; the historical reasons are not particularly easy to track down.

Comment: @KeithThompson you're right, I missed that part about function definition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason seems to be mostly historical.

Prior to the 1989 ANSI C standard, C did not have prototypes. Parameters of type `int` could be defined implicitly; parameters of types other than `int` had to be defined explicitly, before the opening `{`.

For example, where in modern C we might write:

```
double sum(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

in pre-ANSI (K&R) C we had to write:

```
double sum(x, y)
double x;
double y;
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The body of the function might begin with a declaration of a local variable:

```
double sum(x, y)
double x;
double y;
{
    double z;
    /* ... */
}
```

The opening `{` was needed to separate the parameter definitions from the body of the function, and the closing `}` was needed to match the opening `{`.

(This syntax is still allowed, but obsolescent, in modern C; it's not allowed in C++.)

When prototypes were added to the language, there was no particular reason to permit omitting the `{` and `}` in function definitions.

The trivial answer is that that's what the language grammar requires.  The syntax for a *function-definition* is:

> *declaration-speciﬁers declarator declaration-list<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*

where a *compound-statement* consists of `{`, followed by 0 or more declarations and statements, followed by `}`. This is the *only* syntax production that requires a *compound-statement*; there are plenty of others that merely require a *statement*.

Interestingly, in C's predecessor language, called B ([documented here](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.html)), the syntax of a function definition was:

```
name ( arguments ) statement
```

The statement was *usually* a compound statement (a block delimited by `{` and `}`), but it wasn't required to be. B did not require, or even allow, arguments and variables to have their types specified, so there was no need to have a particular syntax to separate the parenthesized argument list from the body of the function. In the earliest C reference I can find ([this one, from 1974](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman74.pdf)), the syntax of a function definition had been changed to require a compound statement, probably to accommodate the addition of parameter declarations.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No, this actually answers the question by explaining the rationale for requiring a compound statement rather than a more general statement in a function definition. Both the function in the question and the function in my answer have a return statement, so I don't understand your point. Perhaps you could explain?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: So apparently you wouldn't care to explain.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Oh, I see; I didn't notice that you had posted an answer. I still stand by what I wrote. I've also added some more historical background that you may or may not find interesting.

Answer (score 10):

If it was allowed, there would be no difference between a function declaration:

```
void a();
```

and a function definition for a function doing nothing:

```
void a()
  ;
```

It would add more problems than gain for sure.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the problem is that it is difficult to distinguish this construction

```
int giveMeFive()
return 5;
```

and this construction

```
int giveMeFive() //;
                 ^^^
return 5;
```

That is whether the programmer made a typo.

At present the compiler issues an error. But what to do if such a function definition will be allowed? This will make the program much less clear.

In fact it could be used like a simplified inline function

```
T function( parameter-list ) return expression;
```

However placing a semicolon between the function header and its body

```
T function( parameter-list ) ; return expression;
```

changes the symantic and makes the code unclear.

The difference for example with a while statement is that a semicolon after while statement like this

```
while( condition );
```

does not change the definition of the construction. In any case it is the while statement.

However relative to the function definition the situation is different.

Comment: Is that any different from putting a semicolon at the end of the `if` or `while` expressions mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy Yes there is a difference. When a while statement for example is used it may have an empty statement. However as I understand the function may not have the empty body. It has to have the return statement.

Comment: So, your explanation is essentially [Martin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839040/33732)? That's fine, but it's not the reason you gave in your answer. Your answer says it's to avoid typos, even though the very same typos are already possible with existing constructs.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy  I already explained the difference in my preceding comment. It seems you simply do not know C.